# Quickest way to create stencil bridge in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am going to make a stencil from a compound path and need to create bridges to the "island" areas. Given this image (and the anchor points on the path) what's the quickest way in Adobe Illustrator to cut out a small section of black so that the white part stays connected?

[image: compound path with anchor points]
[image: area to be spliced out]

Comment: draw a line with the line tool?

Comment: @cbourn: Please take a look at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Eraser Tool**:

- Double click the tool to change the size and settings

[image: Eraser tool settings window]

- Select the shape and erase to create the bridge

[image: Eraser tool]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** with no bounding box and assuming the objects to be joined are already a compound object.

You could outline your path (ensure it doesn't have any fill)

Object>path>outline stroke

then select both the object and its 'bridge' and go to the pathfinder palette

click on 'unite'

---

**2.** with a bounding box and assuming **that** and the objects to be joined are already a compound object.

You could outline your path (ensure it doesn't have any fill)

Object>path>outline stroke

then select both the object and its 'bridge' and go to the pathfinder palette

click on 'minus front'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: The easiest way I've found is to first right-click to create outlines. Then create your bridges in a different color than the text & set them ALL in place before going further.]

[image: Select everything, then click "Divide" in the Pathfinder.Select the text and right click and go to "ungroup".]

[image: Select the "Magic Wand" tool and click on any of the bridges (red) and click delete on the keyboard.]

[image: Next select the Magic Wand tool again and select the text color and move it off the artboard.]

[image: eYou'll notice stray items there; delete them then move your text back onto the artboard.]

[image: The last step is to clean it up by selecting the minus on your keyboard or selecting the "Delete Anchor Point Tool" from the left tools pallet. Delete any anchor points that you wish in order to make a smooth surface.]

Adjust the lines using the Direct Selection Tool and you're all finished and ready to cut your stencil!

Comment: hey, can you use some words to describe what is happening in those images? We're looking for _written_ answers... If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!